# How to restrict access to custom application WEBUI in QNAP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, qnap

Good morning everyone,

I am developing an app for QNAP which has also a web interface. In my qpkg.conf I set QPKG_WEBUI and QPKG_USE_PROXY and I can see correctly the Web interface inside the QNAP interface once I am logged in. It seems perfectly integrated with the QNAP interface, BUT, I can see it also writing the right url in my web browser, even if I am not logged in the QNAP and I cleared all possible cache/cookies.

I want to give access to my Web interface only to valid users. Unfortunately I do not know how to do it. I tried to write a .htaccess to deploy with my application, but without any success (obviously I can not modify the apache standard configuration, and with the standard configuration I was not able to do it).

The only thing I found, inside the Apache folder, there is a pwauth executable that let me ask for username/password (even if I do not want to ask, I want only to see if the user is ALREADY logged in). Anyway with the standard apache configuration, the external module is not loaded, then I can not use the pwauth inside the .htaccess. Maybe I could create some custom cgi program that call it, but I would prefer to avoid custom solution, I really would like to follow a "standard" way to do it, it should be one.....

I would like to know if there is some QNAP variable to set in the qpkg.conf file, or some configuration to set in a .htaccess that does what I want: grant the access only if the user is ALREADY logged in.

Thanks very much to everyone, I could not find anything in google or in the official documentation.